# React-sortable-tree - How to get search window

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, treeview

Hi I am implementing tree view. Can somebody help me to get search window.

```
   this.state = {
        treeData: [{ title: 'Region', children: [{ title: 'Substation' }] }],
        searchQuery: null
    };

  <SortableTree
          treeData={this.state.treeData}
          onChange={treeData => this.setState({ treeData })}
          theme={FileExplorerTheme}
          searchQuery={this.state.searchQuery}
          searchMethod={this.props.defaultSearchMethod}
 />
```

I am not able to get search window using this

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this.

```
   <input type="search" onChange={this.handleSearchOnChange} className="form-control" />

    handleSearchOnChange = e => {
        this.setState({
             searchQuery: e.target.value,
         });
      };
```

Comment: searchString doesn't relate to any state op has mentiond